# How do I make an Ubuntu install USB stick in windows?

Tags: installation, windows-vista, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.4 on a blank machine. I want to use a USB stick.How can I do this in Windows??

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Answer (score 1):

Download Rufus from here - https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Read the simple instructions on the website. Download the ubuntu ISO and use rufus to write to the USB stick. 4gb Minimum USB stick size.